# How can I minimize the time complexity of the following question

Tags: java

[image]

**Solution:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    
    for( int c = 0 ; c < t ; c++ ) {
        
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        
        int[] arr = new int[n];

        for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
            
        }
        
        int minBitOp = ( arr[0] & arr[1] ) ^ ( arr[0] | arr[1] );
        
        for( int i = 0 ; i < n - 1 ; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = i + 1 ; j < n ; j++ ) {
                
                int bitOp = ( arr[i] & arr[j] ) ^ ( arr[i] | arr[j] );
                
                System.out.println("i: " + i + ", j: " + j + ", op: " + bitOp);
                
                if ( bitOp < minBitOp ) {
                    minBitOp = bitOp;
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(minBitOp);
        sc.close();
        
        
    }
    
}
```

I have been trying to minimize the time complexity of the above solution

Comment: Your question must be self contained.  When that link rots the question and any answers become useless to future readers. Please [edit] your post and include the actual text of the question.  Also, if the code works this question belongs on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).  Also, the pointing emojis are unnecessary.

Comment: This is doable in linear time, but it takes some work...

Comment: @LouisWasserman Could you hint at the solution? The only thing I've been able to observe is that the formula can be simplified to `A[i] xor A[j]`, but I've no idea how to find the "closest" pair of array elements in linear time.

Comment: Well, first you want the highest bit to be 0 if possible.  Then you want the next-highest bit to be 0 if possible.  And so on.  Collect sets of `A[i]` that xor with each other to set each bit in turn to 0 when possible.

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61249649/minimum-xor-value-given-an-integer-array-a-of-n-integers-find-the-pair-of-int)

Comment: @Alex The solution proposed in that post is based on a sorted array. That alone makes the approach `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: Yes, however I don't see how Louis Wasserman solution works, so I'm not convinced it's O(n). O(nlogn) is better than your current O(n2)

Comment: It's O(n * number of bits), but the number of bits is constant, really.

Answer (score 1):

As you've figured out, the operation on the integers is equivalent to just xor.

Since you want the minimum output, you want the highest bit -- bit 30, for the bounds specified on your input -- to be zero if possible, and then you want 29 to be zero if possible, and so on.  Meaning you want two numbers from your input that have the same 30th bit if possible, then the same 29th bit if possible, and so on.

There are two reasonably algorithmically nice solutions.  The simpler one is O(n log n), described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61249649/869736): the two numbers with the lowest xor are guaranteed to be next to each other in sorted order, so just sort the input and try xoring each consecutive value.  This is likely to be fastest for your problem.

I will describe the O(n * number of bits) solution, though.  Pseudocode:

```
candidateGroups = a list containing the list of the entire input
for bitIndex from 30 to 0
  nextCandidateGroups = empty list
  for each group in candidateGroups:
    for bitValue from 0 to 1
      let groupI be the elements of group that have the bit at bitIndex = bitValue
      if groupI.size >= 2 then add it to nextCandidateGroups
    
    let group0 be the elements of group that have the bit at bitIndex = 0
    let group1 be the elements of group that have the bit at bitIndex = 1
    if group0 has at least two elements, add it to nextCandidateGroups
    if group1 has at least two elements, add it to nextCandidateGroups
  if nextCandidateGroups is not empty, then let candidateGroups = nextCandidateGroups
take any element of candidateGroups, take out any two elements, return their XOR
```

This requires, for each bitIndex, that you iterate through the groups and iterate through each element of the group.  But that's O(n), since each element is in at most one group.  So the whole algorithm is O(n * number of bits).